How to change the colours of the scroll bar and the active web browser tab
Has there been an update to this?
How to change the color of the scroll bar?
I've tried various recent (24.04) flavours of Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Wubuntu, Lubuntu, etc) as well as Ubuntu itself and cannot find a solution to the problem.
Users who are visually affected (but not completely blind) need a way to make access to computers easier. Hopefully the Linux community can do what Microsoft cannot.
THANKS!

Your question appears to be based on misunderstanding. Each Ubuntu flavor will have a different desktop & thus scrolls bars & theming will be independent of each other. Web Browsers however are user applications, and thus may or may not use the desktop/OS defaults, as it'll depend on decisions made by the developers of that app (and what toolkits they use; some use the same toolkit/libraries as used by the base OS/desktop, others do not which means OS settings are irrelevant).  Your detail is asking about user level software, but you don't even mention what software you're asking about.

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   Wubuntu is NOT a Ubuntu system, so your question isn't even specific to Ubuntu

You can change the colour of the scrollbar, along with the colour of the menu bar etc., by installing a firefox theme :
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/themes/
